# Mapping multiple elements in a cell in a dataframe to another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a table with just one column :

```
df <- data.frame(Interest = c("a,b,c,d,e","a,b,d","e,c,b","d,f"))

Interest  
----
a,b,c,d,e  
a,b,d  
e,c,b  
d,f
```

Another dataframe

```
df1 <- data.frame(Key = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), Value = c("1","2","3","4","5","6"))

Key  | Value  
----  
a  |  1  
b  |  2  
c  |  3  
d  |  4  
e  |  5  
f  |  6
```

Expected output is:

```
df <- data.frame(Interest = c("a,b,c,d,e","a,b,d","e,c,b","d,f"), Mapped = c("1,2,3,4,5","1,2,4","5,3,2","4,6"))

Interest  |  Mapped  
----
a,b,c,d,e  |  1,2,3,4,5  
a,b,d  |  1,2,4  
e,c,b  |  5,3,2  
d,f  |  4,6
```

One to one mapping is fairly simple job. But in this case i have a list that needs to be mapped. Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Please post into your question your data using the output of `dput` or in code rather than in the current format. It is currently fairly difficult to access and we don't really know the true underlying structure without this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you need this output format, but this code will provide what you want.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df$Id=1:dim(df)[1]
df=df %>%
    transform(input = strsplit(input, ",")) %>%
    unnest(input)
df=merge(df,map,by.x='input',by.y='key',all.x=T)
df%>%group_by(Id)%>%dplyr::summarise(Interest=paste(input,collapse = ","),Mapped=paste(value,collapse = ","))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
     Id  Interest    Mapped
  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>
1     1 a,b,c,d,e 1,2,3,4,5
2     2     a,b,d     1,2,4
3     3     b,c,e     2,3,5
4     4       d,f       4,6
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple `strsplit` with an `sapply` should work:

```
df$Mapped <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Interest), split = ","), 
                    function(x) paste0(df1[match(x, df1$Key), "Value"], collapse = ","))

df
#   Interest    Mapped
#1 a,b,c,d,e 1,2,3,4,5
#2     a,b,d     1,2,4
#3     e,c,b     5,3,2
#4       d,f       4,6
```

Answer (score 1):

My smaller dataset because I'm lazy:

```
interest = data.frame(interest = c('a,b,c', 'a,c'))
keyvalue = data.frame(kv = c('a|1', 'b|2', 'c|3'))
```

Could use `qdap::mgsub`. To do some of the 'heavy lifting'

Specifically we take the key value pair and create a two column data.frame using tidyr's separate. Then use `qdap::mgsub` to gsub a vector of patterns and replacements.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
keyv <- keyvalue %>% separate(kv, into = c('Interest', 'Value'), sep = '\\|')
library(qdap)
interest$interest <- paste0(interest$interest,
                            '|',
                            mgsub(keyv$Interest, keyv$Value, interest$interest))
```

Output:

```
     interest
1 a,b,c|1,2,3
2     a,c|1,3
```

Comment: I like your answer ~ But I OP just modified the input data type ~

Comment: Looks like the input data just allows to no longer have to use `tidyr::separate` since the key value pair is already in two columns. Thanks for pointing it out